# Using Python & Selenium to send message to friend in Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, testing

I am currently writing a script in Python to log in on facebook and I want to send message to a friend. The script logs in to my facebook, and it manages to find my friend, but the message is not sent. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the problem is in the div tag/CSS on the text area (I commented out that piece of code).

Screenshot:
[Text doesn't appear here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it9bZ.png)

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\path\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username_box.send_keys(USEREMAIL)
passElem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
passElem.send_keys(USERPASSWORD)
passElem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
userTargetUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/" + "USERTAGET"
driver.get(userTargetUrl)

//The problem is here I think
    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div textarea.uiTextareaNoResize")


    while True:
        elem.send_keys("Test")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_t").click()
```

The error code i get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"css selector","selector":"div textarea.uiTextareaNoResize"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 
(5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Comment: Scrapping `Facebook` is against their **ToS**. Use `Facebook APIs` instead.

Comment: What is the html element you are trying to find? I couldn't find anything with `uiTextareaNoResize`

Comment: Reply to comment 1: I have also tried with Facebook API, but it appears to be an old API and didnt work with it..

Reply to comment 2: I have edited my question and added picture to it so you can see where the problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on [RU SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919234/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-xpath-selenium-facebook-%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/919670#919670))))

Briefly in steps:

1. Making the library import

   `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`
2. Visited the site
3. Logged in
4. You have a friend list, you clicked on your friend's icon and a chat window has opened.

*now what to do?))*

4. You need to place the cursor in the input line, in which the text is not written) Use for this `.click ()`, you can use any of your XPath, but here is a shorter one))

   `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-editor]").click()`
5. After pressing the `.click ()` method, the cursor is placed in the text input area. And now we need to enter the text, but use `.send_keys()` not with the pointer to the element, as you tried, but separately as an action (this is what the imported library is for)
   `actions = ActionChains(driver)
   actions.send_keys('HI')
   actions.perform()`

Woo a la))))

[image]

Well, after that `.click()` on the send icon or press Enter)))))

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the element by name, id, text or any other unique parameter - it would be better (they sometimes change the design and all xpaths and css-selectors become useless).

I made bold what I'd use:

```html
    <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_7" aria-describedby="js_0"
aria-expanded="false" <b>aria-label="Введите сообщение..."</b> 
class="notranslate _5rpu" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" 
style="outline: medium none currentcolor; -moz-user-select: text; 
white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;" <b>tabindex="9999"<b>
 <b>id="js_d"</b> contenteditable="true"><div data-contents="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer but I cannot put this in my python code as it is supposed to be a testing code..